# PostgreSQL Trigger to update MSSQL Database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, triggers, odbc

I have a postgreSQL database with data that I need to access from a database on SQL Server. I've tried creating a linked server utilizing an ODBC driver to postgres but got many data type conversion errors. Now I am looking into the option of having an exact replication of the data in SQL Server and updating it from a trigger in postgres. So everytime the postgres table gets updated it'll trigger an update in the SQL Server database.

Is this possible in postgres and what is the syntax for it?

Comment: You will need to get [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw) running on your Postgres server. Then you can access the SQL Server table as a "foreign table" and have your trigger write to it.

Comment: the documenttation says this: "The current version does not yet support JOIN push-down, or write operations." Does that mean I won't be able to write to the foreign table?

Comment: Then you'll probably need something like https://debezium.io/